# Reformat and return textarea input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Can someone help me with a working html/jquery script that will read the text input of an html textarea box and test if the text input on the box contains a numeric string of 11 characters as part of its content, if it does, the script should come up with a dialog box that will ask if the client will like to reformat that numeric content of the textarea box. if the yes option of the dialog box is selected by the client, the script should then reformat the numeric string by adding spaces after the 3rd, 6th and 9th characters e.g change 08293434565 to 082 934 345 65, and thereafter return the reformatted data into the html textarea box

```js
function Confirm() {

  var data = $('#fix').val();
  var arr = data.split(' ');

  //check if numeric and 11 numbers
  if (isNaN(arr[5]) == true && arr[5].length == 11) {

    //show popup, if yes run the format function
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (window.confirm("Message contains numeric characters which might make the message not delivered to some networks. Do you want us to reformat the message ?. This might increase the numbers of pages of the message and the cost?")) {
      confirm_value.value = "Yes";
      format();
    } else {
      confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);


  }
}

function format() {

  var first = arr[5].substring(0, 4);
  var second = arr[5].substring(4, 20);
  second = second.replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1 ")

  $('#fix').val("This is my mobile number " + first + " " + second);

};
```

```html
<input type="textbox" id="fix" name="fix" />
<button ID="button1" OnClick="Confirm();" runat="server">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, i have. i just posted it

Comment: Your code looks close. I don't think you should only be looking at the 6th element in the split array (arr[5]), and instead should iterate over all elements or try RegExp. Your code doesn't seem to be reformatting the string, nor putting it back into the textarea.

Comment: So what problem are you having with this code? It helps to create an example so in this case the ASP code isn't part of the problem. I think I've pulled out the JS and HTML properly, please check. Are you getting any error messages? Are you debugging with F12?

Comment: No error message, and not doing what it is meant to do

Answer (score 0):

Your test for numeric and 11 numbers isn't correct.

```js
function Confirm() {

  var data = $('#fix').val();
 
  //check if numeric and 11 numbers
  if (!isNaN(data) == true && data.length == 11) {

    //show popup, if yes run the format function
    if (window.confirm("Message contains numeric characters which might make the message not delivered to some networks. Do you want us to reformat the message ?. This might increase the numbers of pages of the message and the cost?")) {
      format(data);
    }
  } else {
     alert('Check number format'); 
  }
}

function format(data) {

  var first = data.substring(0, 4);
  var second = data.substring(4, 20);
  second = second.replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1 ")

  $('#fix').val("This is my mobile number " + first + " " + second);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="fix" name="fix" />
<button ID="button1" OnClick="Confirm();" runat="server">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: @ Dave Anderson Please how do i make the script to able to locate the  phone number within a text box that contains other words along side with the numeric value. like "Please feel free to call me on my mobile number 08293434565" . Please note that the length of the content of the text box is a variable and it changes with every client on the web page. Meaning that the position of the phone number in the text box is not fixed